# When an action potential reaches an axon terminal

Tags: action-potential, neuron

I came across the following question in my study of action potentials in neurons:

When an action potential reaches an axon terminal:

A. Na+ channels close.

B. K+ channels open.

C. The interior of the cell becomes positively charged with respect to the exterior.

D. Options A and B are correct.

The correct answer is apparently C. But I want to know, how?

I know that action potential causes part of membrane of the **axon** to become positively charged with respect to the external environment, moving across the membrane (such that when it reaches another part, the previous part returns to its previous negatively charged state) toward the axon terminal.

This question seems (as far as my understanding goes) to refer to the repolarization of the membrane (as the action potential has already passed through the entirety of the axon, so it cannot to my knowledge cause a positive inner charge in the neuron anymore). If that is so, then the peak of depolarization has already been reached. In order for the neuron to reattain its resting potential, repolarization has to occur, which includes the closing of Na+ ion channels and the opening of K+ ion channels.

I might be mistaken, but I would say the answer is D.

Comment: You are mistaken. The question is asking you about what happens in the axon terminal when an AP arrives there.

Comment: Think about how neurotransmitters are released into the synaptic cleft. Whenever something is being released from the cell, think about increasing intracellular $\ce{Ca++}$ level similar to what happens with platelet release reactions.